# Targeting anchor tag to div tag in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

I have menu with anchor tag, on click of menu link I want to open a new jsp page into a div tag on the same as  tag.
My jsp file:

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="music_details.jsp" target="#div_displayfrom">Music</a></li>
      <li><a href="dance_details.jsp" target="#div_displayfrom">Dance</a></li>
 </ul>

<div class="main-container" id="div_displayfrom">

</div>
```

Please help....Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possibly you may use `iframe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery then you can do this:

```
<ul id='mainTabs'>
  <li><a href="music_details.jsp">Music</a></li>
  <li><a href="dance_details.jsp">Dance</a></li>
</ul>
```

then you can do this in jQuery:

```
$('#mainTabs a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#div_displayfrom').load(this.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Jai, your given solution worked well for me......at first run jsp page loaded on same page but not in targeted div, but from 2nd run it started working as needed...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use .load() function to load the page contents into specified div.

```
$('ul > li > a').click(function(){
   $('#div_displayfrom').load($(this).attr('href'));
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot.

The behaviour you describe is that of an `iframe`, not a `div`.

You could fake it by using JavaScript (Ajax) to fetch the content and then put the fetched HTML in the div (but you would have to account for stylesheets, scripts, different URLs that relative URLs in the document will be resolved against, etc). jQuery has a [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to help with this.

Comment: thanks for clearing my doubt @Quentin...I have used Jquery load method as suggested in above answer.

Answer (score -1):

try like this:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="music_details.jsp#div_displayfrom">Music</a></li>
 ....
 </ul>

<div class="main-container" id="div_displayfrom">
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on how this solves the issue